# How to avoid repeated rendering of ggplot when resolution changes

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a problem with ggplot rendering itself when changing the screen resolution especially when I am working with big files which makes my shinyApp busy every time the resolution changes.
Is there a way to avoid this?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data<-mtcars
  for(i in 1:15){
    data<-rbind(data,data)
  }


  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(aa,aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_point()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you just want to hard-code a width and height for your plot? What exactly do you want to happen when you resize the window?

Comment: `fluidPage` adjusts to browser window, `fixedPage` creates a page with default values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
plotOutput("plot", height = "600px", width = "100%")
```

This might fix the image size, so when you change the size of your screen it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried to say is when changing the screen resolution(for example zoom in/zoom out) I can see that we run the renderPlot from the beginning while renderTable dosent do that.
you can run the code and see the prints in the console

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data<-mtcars
  for(i in 1:5){
    data<-rbind(data,data)
  }


  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    print("plot")
    ggplot(data,aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_point()
  })

output$table<-renderTable({
print("table")
head(data)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```